# can't create user without email for an author after converting single site to multisite

Tags: multisite, users, user-roles

We're converting a single site to multisite, and in the process we're seeing something strange with users.  Previously, we could create and update users to use as authors that don't have an email address.  Those users would show on our posts in the Author field and we could select them.

Now that we've converted our site to multisite and are developing our own theme, we've found that the users exist in the Network Admin section as well as on the first site within the network.  And when we try to edit a user (e.g. to add a bio or social media links), we can't save it if it doesn't include an email address.

We want to be able to use some users simply to populate the author field on posts - not to allow these users to log in.  Is that possible to do on a multisite?

Also, we use the Distributor plugin to send the articles from our main site to sub-sites, and even though the user (author) doesn't show in the list of users on the sub-site, the proper author name is displaying on a post and when we click the author name, it is taking us to a list of articles by that author.  Is it using the users on the Network Admin or our first site on the network to do that?

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: By default, WP requires emails for all users. Are you sure you aren't using a plugin such as Co-authors Plus?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  We're not.  I suspect the previous theme might have had something that was changing this behavior.   I'll try switching the theme and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I've compared our old site (using the theme we were using as well as using the Twenty Twenty One theme) do not require email when I add a user.  I took screen shots but it appears I can't post it here.  But when we converted the site to a multisite, the add user screen is completely different.  On the single site, the add user form allows you to provide social media links, etc., but on the multisite, the add user form is just user name and password (both required).  Any ideas?  We aren't using the plugins that were mentioned to change this behavior.

Comment: I think I found it.  I believe it is a combination of ProfilePress and PowerKit that is making it so we can add users without an email.  I'm going to verify that before I post an answer.

Comment: I was mistaken.  It was not the plugins that was causing it.  We were previously using the Authentic theme, which seems to make email optional (can't find how it's doing that in the code).  However, when we use that same theme on a mulltisite with no plugins, the email is still required.  We've tried the plugin Optional Email (https://wordpress.org/plugins/optional-email/) which says it supports multisite, but only on a non-multisite site does it seem to work.  Any so it seems that multisite is the real problem here.  Any ideas on how to make a user email optional on a multisite?